Why is the behavior inconsistent when intersecting type guards?
I want to use type guards so that hasNext can filter out types.
type Queue1 = {
  operation: 'move';
  offset: number;
};

type Queue2 = {
  operation: 'eat';
  food: string;
};

type Queue3 = {
  operation: 'run';
  type: 'fast' | 'slow';
};

type ExampleQueue = Queue1 | Queue2 | Queue3;

export class ExampleEvent {
  queue: Array<ExampleQueue>;

  constructor(queue: Array<ExampleQueue> = []) {
    this.queue = queue;
  }

  get event() {
    return this.queue[0];
  }

  enqueue(value: ExampleQueue) {
    this.queue.push(value);
  }

  dequeue() {
    return this.queue.shift();
  }

  size() {
    return this.queue.length;
  }

  hasNext<T extends ExampleQueue['operation'] = ExampleQueue['operation']>(
    operation?: T
  ): this is ExampleEvent & { event: Extract<ExampleQueue, { operation: T }>; dequeue(): Extract<ExampleQueue, { operation: T }> } {
    if (this.size() <= 0) return false;
    return operation ? this.event.operation === operation : true;
  }
}

I wrote the code above and used it as shown below.
const event = new ExampleEvent();
if (event.hasNext('move')) {
    event.event.offset // correct!
    event.dequeue().offset // error!
}

Why does it work for event.event.offset but not event.dequeue().offset.type?
hasNext<T extends ExampleQueue['operation'] = ExampleQueue['operation']>(
  operation?: T
): this is { event: Extract<ExampleQueue, { operation: T }>; dequeue(): Extract<ExampleQueue, { operation: T }> } & ExampleEvent {
  if (this.size() <= 0) return false;
  return operation ? this.event.operation === operation : true;
}

What's unusual is that when I write it like above, it validates correctly. I don't know what's wrong, it's just that the order is reversed from above.
Also, if I write it like below, I get the result I want.
hasNext<T extends ExampleQueue['operation'] = ExampleQueue['operation']>(
  operation?: T
): this is Omit<ExampleEvent, 'event' | 'dequeue'> & { event: Extract<ExampleQueue, { operation: T }>; dequeue(): Extract<ExampleQueue, { operation: T }> } {
  if (this.size() <= 0) return false;
  return operation ? this.event.operation === operation : true;
}


Intersections of functions are order-dependent and behave like overloads. Does that fully address the question? If so I’ll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Can you explain further how being order-dependent affects this?

Do you know how overloads work? There are multiple call signatures, and when you call it, the first one that matches is selected.  Your deque is either {(): ExampleQueue | undefined; (): Queue1} or {(): Queue1; (): ExampleQueue | undefined} depending on your definition, and since both are zero-arg functions, you'll just get the first one in the list when you call it. I'm happy to elaborate in an actual answer, if you agree that I'm not missing anything.

I completely understand, I don't think I need an example, thanks for your help!

An "example"? I'm confused. Comments don't count as answers, I'm just trying to make sure I understand the question fully before I bother writing up an actual answer (since I tend to spend a while on such answers). It sounds like I do understand it, so I'll write an answer soon.

Intersections of function types are treated as overloads. When you call an overloaded function, TypeScript has to choose an appropriate call signature... and it generally does so by checking each one in order and selecting the first one that matches how you called it.  That allows you to write things like
// overloaded function with two call signatures
declare function foo(a: string): string;
declare function foo(a: unknown): number;

foo("abc").toUpperCase(); // okay, (a: string) => string selected
foo(123).toFixed(); // okay, (a: unknown) => number selected

Note that the above will behave completely differently if you reorder the call signatures:
declare function foo(a: unknown): number;
declare function foo(a: string): string;

foo("abc").toUpperCase(); // error! (a: unknown) => number selected

So overloads are, in general, order dependent, and intersections of functions are equivalent to overloads.  That explains the behavior you're seeing.
Yes, it's weird, since intersections are conceptually order-independent, but functions are an exception to this.

In particular, this fails because event.dequeue has two zero-arg call signatures, the first one of which returns ExampleQueue | undefined:
if (event.hasNext('move')) {
    /* const event: ExampleEvent & {
        event: Queue1;
        dequeue(): Queue1;
    } */
    type Dequeue = typeof event.dequeue
    // type Dequeue = (() => ExampleQueue | undefined) & (() => Queue1)
    event.dequeue().offset // error!
}

If you switch the order of the intersection, it succeeds because now the first zero-arg call signature returnes Queue1:
if (event.hasNext('move')) {
    /* const event: {
         event: Queue1;
         dequeue(): Queue1;
    } & ExampleEvent */
    type Dequeue = typeof event.dequeue
    event.dequeue().offset // okay
    // type Dequeue = (() => Queue1) & (() => ExampleQueue | undefined)
}

But even that really isn't what you want, since you don't intend for there to be two call signatures. So if you Omit the original call signature, then you also get a success:
if (event.hasNext('move')) {
    /* const event: Omit<ExampleEvent, "event" | "dequeue"> & {
         event: Queue1;
         dequeue(): Queue1;
    } */
    type Dequeue = typeof event.dequeue
    // type Dequeue = () => Queue1
    event.dequeue().offset // okay
}

And so it's this third approach that conforms to what you're looking for, and how I'd recommend writing this.
Playground link to code

I understand, but why does event.offset work well when type Dequeue = (() => ExampleQueue | undefined) & (() => Queue1)?

I don't get it, what does event.event.offset have to do with Dequeue? The type of event.event is just ExampleQueue & Queue1 which is Queue1. Intersections of incompatible discriminated union members are never. This is offtopic for the question as asked unless I'm missing something very big here.

I misspoke. I meant to ask why can find event.event.offset in event.event.offset // correct!, but I think I found the answer: because it's a getter, it behaves differently than a function.
